# Create Quote related to Account in Test setup method

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I'm trying to assign account Id to quote, but i can't even compile code, becouse of this error message: **Field is not writeable: Quote.AccountId**

Sample code:

```
Account acc = new Account(name='Test Acc');
insert acc;
Quote qu = new Quote(name='01010', accountId=acc.Id);
```

I know, that Quote has some required fields, but for the sake of simplicity, this sample code is assigning just accountId.

Is there some known workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set the `accountId` of Quote directly. It will be set by Salesforce with the `accountId` of the Opportunity related to this Quote.

Ran this code and print the quote variable and it have the accountId assigned.

```
Account acc = new Account(name='Test Acc');
insert acc;
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id,name = acc.name,closedate = system.today(),stagename='Prospecting');
insert o;
Quote qu = new Quote(name='01010', opportunityId=o.Id);
insert qu;
qu = [select id,name,opportunityid,accountid from quote where id =: qu.id];
system.debug(qu);
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) accountId doesn't have create and update properties and opportunityId just have create property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I suspected as much. Strange that, according to the documentation, the field is writeable. That is to say, it is not explicitly described as 'read-only'.

Comment: @SanderdeJong It is not writeable. It is not creatable and updatable also. See the document link i have provided.

Comment: Hmm. I had seen that page as well and concluded that it was writeable, because it doesn't have the read-only statement that the attribute AdditionalAddress, just below, has. Thanks for the added explanation!